# How to override system_time_zones in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, datetime

How can I override the [system_time_zones](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_time_zones/7)() function without hacking the Drupal 7 core?

I would like to modify how the dropdown list is presented, but cannot seem to get at it with [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)().

My end goal here is to reformat the timezone dropdown list to include only the location and offset by removing the date/time from the `<select>` lists `<options>` text.

For example,

'`Pacific/Honolulu: Friday, June 1, 2012 - 6:43pm -1000`' would change to
'`Pacific/Honolulu: -1000`'

This would be a simple edit to [system_time_zones](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_time_zones/7)() in system.module, but hacking core is not an option for me.

If I *were* to hack core, this is what I would like to do.

Before Edits (for reference):

```
function system_time_zones($blank = NULL) {
  $zonelist = timezone_identifiers_list();
  $zones = $blank ? array('' => t('- None selected -')) : array();
  foreach ($zonelist as $zone) {
    // Because many time zones exist in PHP only for backward compatibility
    // reasons and should not be used, the list is filtered by a regular
    // expression.
    if (preg_match ('!^((Africa|America|Antarctica|Arctic|Asia|Atlantic|Australia|Europe|Indian|Pacific)/|UTC$)!', $zone)) {
      $zones[$zone] = t('@zone: @date', array('@zone' => t(str_replace ('_', ' ', $zone)), '@date' => format_date(REQUEST_TIME, 'custom', variable_get('date_format_long', 'l, F j, Y - H:i') . ' O', $zone)));
    }
  }
  // Sort the translated time zones alphabetically.
  asort ($zones);
  return $zones;
}
```

After Edits (Changes are to $zones[$zone] in @zone string):

```
function system_time_zones($blank = NULL) {
  $zonelist = timezone_identifiers_list();
  $zones = $blank ? array('' => t('- None selected -')) : array();
  foreach ($zonelist as $zone) {
    // Because many time zones exist in PHP only for backward compatibility
    // reasons and should not be used, the list is filtered by a regular
    // expression.
    if (preg_match ('!^((Africa|America|Antarctica|Arctic|Asia|Atlantic|Australia|Europe|Indian|Pacific)/|UTC$)!', $zone)) {
      $zones[$zone] = t('@zone: @date', array('@zone' => t(str_replace ('_', ' ', $zone)), '@date' => format_date(REQUEST_TIME, 'custom', ' O', $zone)));
    }
  }
  // Sort the translated time zones alphabetically.
  asort ($zones);
  return $zones;
}
```

How can I accomplish this without messing with core?

Comment: Use hook_date_timezone_process_alter - just answered this here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89949/how-do-i-get-the-timezone-form-reference-on-a-date-field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to access the timezone dropdown list by implementing [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7)() with an [#after_build](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#after_build) function.  You can filter, clean and modify the array here.

```
function MYMODULE_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
   $form['#after_build'][] = 'MYMODULE_timezone_modify';
}

function MYMODULE_timezone_modify($form, &$form_state) {
   $form['timezone']['timezone']['#options'] = array(/*Your New or Modified Array Here*/);
   return $form;
}
```

Comment: This works great for the user profile page but any idea how to implement this for a date field with a time zone selection?  I can't seem to find where the time zone options are set in the $form variable.

Comment: See answer to my question at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89949/how-do-i-get-the-timezone-form-reference-on-a-date-field